# Give a CSS border arrow a border on 1 side

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am hoping someone can help me with trying to find a nice elegant way of getting a border on a CSS arrow border.

I am trying to create this:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="message-container customer">
    <p class="message">Great thanks</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.message {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 66%;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border-right: 4px solid #0892cb;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.message:after {
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-right: -14px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

Here is a working JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kdeo3wpg/

As you can see I have a blue border on the right of he main message, but I cannot figure out a way to get the blue border on the arrow as well. If at all possible I would really like to avoid using an image. It would be great to find a CSS only solution.

I have thought about trying to use the `:before` sudo element but I can't get the full control I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to find a solution, but to be honest it is not very clean.

https://jsfiddle.net/kdeo3wpg/1/

What I have done is add a new element which is the width of the border and has the same background colour. I then set the height to slightly less than the height of the CSS arrow. I then give my new element a CSS arrow the background colour of the border.

Here is the new code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="message-container customer">
    <p class="message">
        Great thanks
        <span class="arrow-border"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.message {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 66%;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-right: 4px solid #0892cb;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.message:after {
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-right: -14px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  }

.arrow-border {
    position: absolute;
    background: #0892cb;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    bottom: -9px;
    right: -4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.arrow-border:after {
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #0892cb;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin-right: -3px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

While this solution works, I feel there could be a better and cleaner options so I am still open to suggestions.

Comment: It's intriguing but TBH, these days I'd be using an SVG.

Comment: I have cracked it: https://jsfiddle.net/kdeo3wpg/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D How would you do this with SVG? Would you have an SVG for just the arrow or the whole speech bubble?

Comment: The whole bubble . SVG is very scalable.

Comment: @Paulie_D would you be able to provide an example using an SVG? You don't need to create the actual arrow as an SVG, just a box for example sake would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `svg` you could create your text bubble and apply `linearGradient` to it.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="-1 -1 102 52">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad">
      <stop offset="97%" stop-color="#fff" />
      <stop offset="97%" stop-color="#237ACB" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,5 a5,5 0 0,1 5,-5 h95 v45 l-10,-10 h-85 a5,5 0 0,1 -5,-5" fill="url(#grad)" />
  <text x="50%" y="40%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="10">Great Thanks</text>
</svg>
```

---

For a text bubble to have dynamic text, you'll need to use the triangle as an `svg`. The text will be outside the `svg`.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}
#text {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff calc(100% - 3px), #237ACB calc(100% - 3px));
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
#tri {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="tri" width="15" height="15" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad">
        <stop offset="79%" stop-color="#fff" />
        <stop offset="79%" stop-color="#237ACB" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0,0 h15 v15 l-15,-15" fill="url(#grad)" />
  </svg>
  <div id="text">Text bubble that will change its width to <code>max-width</code>(200px) and height to contain the dynamic text</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Applying `box-shadow`:

To add a `box-shadow` to the `svg` you'll have to apply an svg `filter` on the path. Doing it through CSS won't work since CSS can't see the actual path.

`feFuncA` element's `slope` attribute controls the opacity of the shadow, `feOffset` is self explanatory.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}
#text {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 66%;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-right: 5px solid #0892cb;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#tri {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="tri" width="15" height="18" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 18">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad">
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#fff" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#0892cb" />
      </linearGradient>
      <filter id="shadow" height="130%">
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" in="SourceAlpha" result="offout" />
        <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1" />
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode/>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0,0 h15 v15 l-15,-15" filter="url(#shadow)" fill="url(#grad)" />
  </svg>
  <div id="text">Text bubble that will change its width to <code>max-width</code>(200px) and height to contain the dynamic text</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Reusing the `svg`:

To use the same `svg` `path` multiple times, you could define the `path` element within the `defs` element and use it multiple times using the `use` element as shown in the example below.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.containerIn, .containerOut {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 4px 0 15px;
}
.text {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 66%;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-right: 5px solid #0892cb;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.containerIn .text {
  border: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid #689F38;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  float: left;
}

.tri {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  right: 0;
}
.containerIn .tri {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="15" height="18" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 18">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradRight">
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#fff" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#0892cb" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="gradLeft">
      <stop offset="31%" stop-color="#689F38" />
      <stop offset="31%" stop-color="#fff" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="shadow" height="130%">
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" in="SourceAlpha" result="offout" />
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <path id="triRight" d="M0,0 h15 v15z" filter="url(#shadow)" fill="url(#gradRight)" />
    <path id="triLeft" d="M0,0 v15 l15,-15z" filter="url(#shadow)" fill="url(#gradLeft)" />
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="containerOut">
  <svg class="tri" width="15" height="18" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 18">
    <use xlink:href="#triRight" x="0" y="0" />
  </svg>
  <div class="text">Text bubble that will change its width to <code>max-width</code>(200px) and height to contain the dynamic text</div>
</div>

<div class="containerIn">
  <svg class="tri" width="15" height="18" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 18">
    <use xlink:href="#triLeft" x="0" y="0" />
  </svg>
  <div class="text">Text bubble that will change its width to <code>max-width</code>(200px) and height to contain the dynamic text</div>
</div>

<div class="containerIn">
  <svg class="tri" width="15" height="18" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 18">
    <use xlink:href="#triLeft" x="0" y="0" />
  </svg>
  <div class="text">Text bubble that will change its width to <code>max-width</code>(200px) and height to contain the dynamic text</div>
</div>

<div class="containerOut">
  <svg class="tri" width="15" height="18" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 18">
    <use xlink:href="#triRight" x="0" y="0" />
  </svg>
  <div class="text">Text bubble that will change its width to <code>max-width</code>(200px) and height to contain the dynamic text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good. What I should have mentioned is this is for a live messaging application, which will need to be highly accessible for screen readers and so on. I think having the text inside an SVG element will cause me issues here. Also it creases the complication when it comes to display new messages.

Comment: I had a look at your new solution and I like what you have done but there is an issue with the shadows, I have created a fiddle to demonstrate https://jsfiddle.net/aapyjrjn/

Comment: @lukehillonline - To apply a `box-shadow` to an `svg` element, you have to define an inline `filter` element. I've added an example.

Comment: Very nice, with only a little change you can make it look like a real messaging app https://jsfiddle.net/aapyjrjn/1/

Comment: @AndrewBone - Indeed :) Btw, there's a clean way to reuse an `svg`, I'll add an example to my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `span` for blue border instead of border on `p` element if you want border to be bigger then element. Also you need to adjust positions.

This will work only on white background.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: white;
}
.message {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 66%;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.message:after {
  bottom: -9px;
  right: -5px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(177, 177, 177, .07), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
span {
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% + 18px);
  border-right: 5px solid #0892cb;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:after {
  content: '';
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  right: -3px;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="message-container customer">
  <p class="message">Great thanks <span></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

You can also use `SVG`

```css
body {
  background: #F4F4F3;
}
.st0 {
  fill: #B2B3B3;
}
.st1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.st2 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
.st3 {
  fill: none;
}
.st4 {
  fill: #3079BE;
}
.st5 {
  font-size: 20;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="260.5px" height="120.5px" viewBox="0 0 260.5 120.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 260.5 120.5;" xml:space="preserve">

  <path class="st0" d="M256.016,20.217l0.961,97.533l-22.195-22L24.75,96.167c-6.653,0-11.417-5.834-11.917-10.972V20.217
 c0-6.429,5.389-11.637,12.042-11.637h219.099c3.51,0,12.041,0,12.041,0S256.016,17.182,256.016,20.217z" />
  <g>
    <path class="st2" d="M256.018,15.976v99.42l-21.16-20.42H25.688c-6.63,0-12-5.38-12-12v-67c0-6.63,5.37-12,12-12h218.33
  c3.499,0,12,0,12,0S256.018,12.845,256.018,15.976z" />
    <polygon class="st4" points="256.5,116.524 249.813,110.064 249.813,4.493 256.643,4.493  " />
  </g>
  <rect x="84.5" y="36" class="st3" width="109.5" height="19.75" />
  <text x="50%" y="60px" text-anchor="middle" class="st1 st5">Great thanks</text>
  <path class="st0" d="M234.448,97.333" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @nenard Almost there, but the blue border need to end within the arrow. So the end of the border will also be an arrow.

Comment: I updated my answer, but again this will work on white background because you basically mask part of border with pseudo element.

Comment: @NenadVracar your update is better but having a white triangle blocks the shadow

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking to create this design using a single element, you may be able to use pseudo elements in order to make use of the likes of a Skew to create the bottom triangle as well as a border-right on these elements to create the blue section.

A quick demo can be seen below:

```css
.message{
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:100px;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  padding-right:30px;
  background:lightgray;
  border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #222;
  }
.message:before,.message:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:0;
  height:100%;
  width:20px;
  background:inherit;
  border-right:5px solid cornflowerblue;
  }
.message:before{
  height:50%;top:50%;
  width:10px;
  box-shadow:inherit;
  transform:skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="message">I'm Doing Well Thanks</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

already answered, but wih a single element and a pseudo + gradient, it could be done quiet similar.

```css
body {
  background: #F4F4F3;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 3px -2px gray;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px;
}

span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  /* from here it is a matter of tunning */
  bottom:-10px;
  width:4.5em;/* see this to increase/decrease angle */
  background:linear-gradient(230deg, #237ACB 50%,transparent 50% ) no-repeat top right,/* degrees to follow width/angle set earlier */
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, #FFFFFF 50%, gray calc(50% + 1px) , transparent calc(50% + 2px)  );/* about blending bg and drawing the the slant bottom shadow */
  background-size:5px 197%, auto auto;/* about to draw the blue line just as big as it needs */
  z-index:-1;
  right:-11px;/* tune about width /angle given earlier */
}
```

```html
<span> Great thanks</span>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qNyAVa

Comment: Looks good but the angle of the blue border is slightly off, I tried to tweak it but I cannot get it to look right.

Comment: @lukehillonline with transform:scale, it might be easier to see if it can be tuned: i updated http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qNyAVa (transform + shadows , deg, bg-size ... ) It remains an hint :)